# Aligning brackets

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

Hi is there anyway to get the two left `[` brackets on the first and second lines to align?

```
\begin{align}
&\quad[v^{*}a^{-} +va^{\dagger}_{-k}]e^{+ik_{z}\centerdot z}=[u^{*}b^{-} +ub^{\dagger}_{-k}]e^{+ik_{z}\centerdot z} \nonumber \\ 
& \Rightarrow [\alpha u^{*}a^{-} +\beta u a^{-}+\alpha^{*}u a^{\dagger}_{-k}+\beta^{*} u^{*}a^{+}_{-k}]e^{+ik_{z}\centerdot z}=[u^{*}b^{-} +ub^{\dagger}_{-k}]e^{+ik_{z}\centerdot z} 
\end{align}
```

Comment: Use `\mathrel{\phantom{\Rightarrow}}` for the first `\quad`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel It does not look like a duplicate to me. Here we have the problem of understanding alignment points.

Comment: @mafp: If you reference the alignment, the duplicated question is the wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    & [v^{*}a^{-} +va^{\dagger}_{-k}]e^{+ik_{z}\centerdot z}=[u^{*}b^{-} +ub^{\dagger}_{-k}]e^{+ik_{z}\centerdot z} \nonumber \\
    \Rightarrow & [\alpha u^{*}a^{-} +\beta u a^{-}+\alpha^{*}u a^{\dagger}_{-k}+\beta^{*} u^{*}a^{+}_{-k}]e^{+ik_{z}\centerdot z}=[u^{*}b^{-} +ub^{\dagger}_{-k}]e^{+ik_{z}\centerdot z}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: you'll get nicer spacing between the `\Rightarrow` and the opening bracket if you insert `{}` between them.